# Weird Spacing Issue

Tags: position, spacing

Hello im trying to figure out a weird spacing issue here: http://22twenty.com/wordpress and if you go to any page other then the home you will see that all the data below the header is pushed down. hope someone can help,

Denver

Answer (score 1):

You've set a height of 504px on the header. You've done this to achieve a visual effect rather than mark up your content correctly.  You should correctly markup your header, footer, and content areas and, if you wish, position your footer at the bottom of the page rather than give your header 504px of height just to accommodate a background image.

Comment: Im sorry so to get gradient which is the background image for my header how would i do it?